# Get descriptors of spesific pixels in image python

Tags: python, opencv, feature-extraction, descriptor

I'm trying to get descriptors of spesific pixels of an image. Not keypoints. (Like the pixel 100,100)

Is there any way to doing that via sift or other algorithm, preferably something available in opencv?

Thanks.

Comment: yes, just call the `compute()` method on whatever points you like. did you try that? did you find the docs for `Feature2D`, the superclass of SIFT?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks. You can post this as a solution and I will accept as that.